# Ember.js debugging: how to alter controller property via console?

Tags: debugging, ember.js

I frequently have a template outputting a property like this:

**template**

```
some thing with a value of {{value}}
```

**controller**

```
App.ItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    value: function() { 
        return this.get('baseCost') * 1.10;
    }.property('baseCost'),
    baseCost: 100;
});
```

Since `value` observes `baseCost` I expect that `{{value}}` will change when baseCost changes.

How can I change baseCost via the inspector console to test this?  Something like:

```
> var ic = App.ItemsController.create();
> ic.set('baseCost', 200);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will cause an infinite loop because you use itself to calculate itself, additionally you shouldn't have the `;`...  throw a `debugger` statement in the value property and change it in the locals window.  Additionally using ember inspector in the view tree you can click on a particular controller, then click on the controller you'd like to edit, and edit individual properties.

```
value: function() { 
    return this.get('baseCost') * 1.10;
}.property('baseCost'),

baseCost: 100
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EYECePUD/1/edit

You can definitely do that,

```
var a = App.ApplicationController.create();

a.set('baseCost', 200);
alert(a.get('value'));
```

Comment: Whoops, your totally right.  I was trying to write up an example off the top of my head - I don't have a working example on my side. Still, how can I change `baseCost` to test dependent functionality without building out Ember actions?  Can't I just change that data in the inspector console?

Comment: See updated portion, honestly the easiest thing is to toss in an input box and bind it to the value, like I did in the jsbin, it's way faster than going through ember inspector, but they both work.